# изменение основного цикла wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Нужно чтобы на странице категорий выводились посты только с определенным тегом, при этом посты самой категории не должны учитываться. Т.е. нужно изменить содержимое основного запроса. 
Если делать запрос через new wp_query то ломается пагинация.
На данный момент есть вот такой код в файле functions.php:

```
function pre_get_post_by_tag( $query )
{
  if ( is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
      $query->set('tag', 'boys');
  }
}
add_action('get_post_by_tag', 'pre_get_post_by_tag' );
```

boys - название тега.

и вызов в файле archive.php

```
do_action('get_post_by_tag');
```

сейчас выдает ошибку  "Fatal error: Call to a member function is_main_query() on string in...."

Как исправить ошибку? Правильно ли изменять запрос таким образом? Может есть какието другие способы добиться желаемого? Буду рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `add_action('get_post_by_tag', 'pre_get_post_by_tag' );`

Похоже надо

`add_action('pre_get_posts', 'pre_get_post_by_tag' );`

См [дополнительно](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/pre_get_posts)